# A problem about maxmium modulus principle

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathcal{H} = \{x+iy |x \in \mathbb{ R},y > 0\}$, the upper half plane. Let $f \colon  \mathcal H \to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded holomorphic function such that $f$ continuously extends to the real axis . Let $M = \sup_{x\in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)|$. Show that $\sup_{z \in \mathcal H} |f(z)|= M$.

I tried to solve this problem on the semi-disk centered on 0, and I found the $\sup |f(z)|$ is either on the circle or the diameter. But I don't how to deaol with it then.

Comment: Firstly, There exists $z_n \in H$ such that $|f(z_n)| \rightarrow M$. So $M'=sup{|f(z)|:z \in H}\geq M$.  Now By maximum modulus principle M' is attained on the boundary which implies $M'=M$

Comment: My answer below may be an overkill but it is a MMP for unbounded regions. I hope some users will benefit from the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a more general result:

Let $\Omega$ be a region which is not dense in $\mathbb C$. If $f$ is a bounded holomorphic function on $\Omega$ which extends to a  continuous function on $\overline {\Omega}$ then $sup \{|f(z)| : z \in \Omega\}=sup \{|f(z)| : z \in \partial \Omega\}$.

Since $\Omega $ is not dense in $%
%TCIMACRO{\U{2102} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{C}
%EndExpansion
$ there is an open ball disjoint from $\Omega $. By translation we may
assume that $B(0,\delta )\cap \Omega =\emptyset .$ Fix $z_{0}\in \Omega .$
Let $\epsilon >0$ and $n$ be a positive integer such that $(\left\vert
z_{0}\right\vert /\delta )^{1/n}<1+\epsilon .$ Let $R>\max \{\left\vert
z_{0}\right\vert ,\delta (\frac{M_{1}}{M})^{n}\}$ where $M_{1}$ is a bound
for $f$ on $\Omega .$ Then $z_{0}\in C$ for some component $C$ of $\Omega
\cap B(0,R).$ We now apply Maximum Modulus Principle to the function $\frac{%
f^{n}(z)}{z}$ on $C$ [ Here $f^{n}(z)=[f(z)]^{n}$, not the $n-th$ derivative
of $f$ at $z$]. Since the $\partial C\subset \partial (\Omega \cap
B(0,R))\subset \partial \Omega \cup \partial B(0,R)$ we see that $\left\vert 
\frac{f^{n}(z)}{z}\right\vert \leq \max \{\frac{M_{1}^{n}}{R},\frac{M^{n}}{%
\delta }\}$ on $\partial C$ since $B(0,\delta )\cap \Omega =\emptyset .$
Thus, by Maximum Modulus Principle we get $\left\vert f(z_{0})\right\vert
\leq \left\vert z_{0}\right\vert ^{1/n}\max \{\frac{M_{1}}{R^{1/n}},\frac{M}{%
\delta ^{1/n}}\}=\left\vert z_{0}\right\vert ^{1/n}\frac{M}{\delta ^{1/n}}$
in view of the fact that $R>\delta (\frac{M_{1}}{M})^{n}.$ Finally, since $%
(\left\vert z_{0}\right\vert /\delta )^{1/n}<1+\epsilon $ we get $\left\vert
f(z_{0})\right\vert \leq M(1+\epsilon ).$ Since $z_{0}\in \Omega $ and $%
\epsilon >0$ are arbitrary we are done.

Answer (score 0):

To make the answer as specific as the statement: consider $p: z \in \mathcal{H} \longmapsto \frac{z-i}{z+i} \in D$ the biholomorphism and $g=f \circ p^{-1}$.

$g$ is holomorphic bounded on the unit disk, and extends continuously to a continuous function $g_1$ on the boundary of said disk (with $g_1$ bounded by $M$ on the boundary and by, say, $Q$, on the entire disk), minus one point (here, $1$, as pointed in the comments). We want to show that this implies that $|g| \leq M$.

Using Blaschke factors (ie the boundary-preserving biholomorphisms of the disk $z \longmapsto \frac{z-w}{1-z\overline{w}}$ for $w \in D$), it is enough to show that $|g(0)| \leq M$.

Let $0 < r <1$, $0 < \epsilon < 1/2$.

We have $|g(0)| \leq \left|\int_0^1{g(re^{2i\pi\theta})d\theta}\right| \leq \int_{\epsilon}^{1-\epsilon}{|g(re^{2i\pi\theta})|d\theta} + 2\epsilon Q$.

Letting $r$ go to $1$ and using dominated convergence, it follows $|g(0)| \leq (1-2\epsilon)M+2\epsilon Q$.

This holds for any $\epsilon$ so we are done.

Comment: This doesn't work because the inverse is not defined at $z=1$.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll edit.